# React MaterialTable v4 - Row Unique Id

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MaterialTable **v4**, and I'm trying to get rid of a warning:

> The table requires all rows to have an unique id property. A row was
> provided without id in the rows prop. To prevent the loss of state
> between renders, please provide an unique id for each row.

I tried adding this:

```
components={{
       Row: props => <MTableBodyRow id="SOME-ROW-ID-HERE" {...props} />
}}
```

But it's complaining about MTableBodyRow:

> Line 1000:40: 'MTableBodyRow' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

How can I fix this warning?